# Can we use numpy array as input to perform Tfidfvectorizer() on text data, inside of make_column_transform()?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding, tfidfvectorizer

I am trying to perform multiple column transformations using `OneHotEncoder()` and `TfidfVectorizer()` on my training data which is a numpy array. I am trying to use `make_column_transformer()` to perform all transformations at once. X_train is my input data.

**Input Data**

```
print(X_train.shape)
>>> (75117, 6)
```

Sample instance

```
print(X_train[5,:])
>>> ['electrical_contractor_license-electrical_contractor_license-general_contractor_license-refrigeration_contractor_lic.'
 'brennan_heating_company_inc' 'instal new electr boiler'
 'single_family_/_duplex' 0.0 0]
```

**Column Transformation code**

```
column_trans = make_column_transformer(
    (OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, handle_unknown='ignore'), [0, 1, 3]),
    (TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words='english', lowercase=False), [2]),
     remainder='passthrough')

z = column_trans.fit_transform(X_train)
```

Using the above code, `OneHotEncoder()` works fine on columns `(0, 1, 3)` but when I add `TfidfVectorizer()` for column `2` it throws the following error.

`TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`

Full Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1167-68498e1c856a> in <module>
      4      remainder='passthrough')
      5 
----> 6 z = column_trans.fit_transform(X_train)
      7 print(z[0,:].shape)
      8 print(z[0,:])

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    516         self._validate_remainder(X)
    517 
--> 518         result = self._fit_transform(X, y, _fit_transform_one)
    519 
    520         if not result:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in _fit_transform(self, X, y, func, fitted)
    455                     message=self._log_message(name, idx, len(transformers)))
    456                 for idx, (name, trans, column, weight) in enumerate(
--> 457                         self._iter(fitted=fitted, replace_strings=True), 1))
    458         except ValueError as e:
    459             if "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead" in str(e):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1005                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1006 
-> 1007             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1008                 pass
   1009 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    833                 return False
    834             else:
--> 835                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    836                 return True
    837 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    752         with self._lock:
    753             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 754             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    755             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    756             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    207     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    208         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 209         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    210         if callback:
    211             callback(result)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    588         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    589         # arguments in memory
--> 590         self.results = batch()
    591 
    592     def get(self):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    254         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    255             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 256                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    257 
    258     def __len__(self):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    254         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    255             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 256                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    257 
    258     def __len__(self):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    726     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    727         if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 728             res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    729         else:
    730             res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
   1857         """
   1858         self._check_params()
-> 1859         X = super().fit_transform(raw_documents)
   1860         self._tfidf.fit(X)
   1861         # X is already a transformed view of raw_documents so

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
   1218 
   1219         vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents,
-> 1220                                           self.fixed_vocabulary_)
   1221 
   1222         if self.binary:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in _count_vocab(self, raw_documents, fixed_vocab)
   1129         for doc in raw_documents:
   1130             feature_counter = {}
-> 1131             for feature in analyze(doc):
   1132                 try:
   1133                     feature_idx = vocabulary[feature]

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in _analyze(doc, analyzer, tokenizer, ngrams, preprocessor, decoder, stop_words)
    103             doc = preprocessor(doc)
    104         if tokenizer is not None:
--> 105             doc = tokenizer(doc)
    106         if ngrams is not None:
    107             if stop_words is not None:

TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

It does work when I use it outside of `make_column_transformer()`, but the reason why I am using `make_column_transformer()` and not separately, is because, if I do `One hot encoding` first and then `tfidf`, then its quite possible that **the number of features generated by one hot encoder might vary**, so hard coding the column index for tfidf might not be a good idea.

```
tf = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words='english')
n = tf.fit_transform(X_train[:,2])
n.toarray()

>>> array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. The solution is to replace:

```
  (TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words='english', lowercase=False), [2]),
```

by

```
  (TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words='english', lowercase=False), 2),
```

Otherwise the TfidfVectorizer, upon calling `fit`, receives 2D data (of shape `(#documents, 1)`) which it can't handle.

It is explained in `ColumnTransformer` [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html?highlight=columntransformer#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer):

> **columns: str, array-like of str, int, array-like of int, array-like of bool, slice or callable**
>
> Indexes the data on its second axis. Integers are interpreted as positional columns, while strings can reference DataFrame columns by name. A scalar string or int should be used where transformer expects X to be a 1d array-like (vector), otherwise a 2d array will be passed to the transformer. [...]